# How many times does the number 111 appear in this sequence?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Let $(a_n)$ be an integer sequence such that $a_1 = 1$ and for $n \geq 1$ positive integer,
$a_ {2n} = a_n + 1$ and $ a_ {2n + 1} $ = $10a_n$ How many times does the number $111$ appear in this sequence?

First $31$ terms of sequence (table):

- $n- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 , 8, 9 , 10 , 11,12,13,14,15,16$

  $a_n - 1, 2, 10, 3, 20, 11, 100, 4, 30 , 21,200,12,110,101,1000,5$

  - $n - 17, 18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,...$

  $a_n - 40,31,300,22,210,201,2000,13,120,1100,...$

I made my way back to the first term, found $14$ times. is there anymore formalized method for finding the right value?

Comment: I presume $10_{a_n}$ means $10$ in base $a_n$, so $a_{2n+1}=a_n$?

Comment: I think so! Not sure, I used a very logical and archaic method

Comment: If my interpretation is correct than $111$ appears infinitely many times. Please give the question definition of $a_n$.

Comment: It is the sequence of integers

Comment: the answer should be the same as how many ways to make $111$ from $1$ by operate $\times10$ and $+1$ each time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get $14$ times.  The number of times $n$ appears is the number of ways to reach $n$ by starting with $1$ and either adding $1$ or multiplying by $10$. If $f(n)$ is the number of ways $n$ appears we have the recurrence
$$f(n)=\begin {cases} 1&n=1\\
f(n-1)&n \not \equiv 0 \pmod {10}\\
f(n-1)+f(\frac n{10})& n \equiv 0 \pmod {10} \end {cases}$$
We have $f(100)=12$ because you can add $1\ 100$ times, you can multiply by $10$ twice, or you can add $1$ a number of times from $0$ to $9$, multiply by $10$ and add $1$ enough other times to get to $100$